# Replace list items nested within certain class

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add html markup to an unordered list with a specific class.

This would be the HTML to start with:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>    
<ul class="foo">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to end up with:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>    
<ul class="foo">
  <li><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>Item 1</li>
  <li><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>Item 2</li>
  <li><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I haven't found a regex that could be used to run a preg_replace() that can get this to work.

The content is created with Wordpress. I want to use a filter that scans the_content and adds the extra markup. In such a manner:

```
function foo_ul($text) {
    //some function
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'foo_ul');
```

I do not want to be reliant on Javascript/jQuery so I would like this to be generated on the server-side.

Any ideas?

Comment: A you sure it's a best way to use php and regexp for this task?

Comment: If you are doing this serverside, I would use a html parser rather than a regex but we would need to know more info - what creates the list? how do you know what class it has? surely if the list is created serverside with php, then you can just add the svg then, etc.  In it's current form, the question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO - please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The content is generated by Wordpress so I'd like to add a filter that scans the content and adds the desired markup in the right places.

Comment: Are you looking something like this: https://regex101.com/r/QkWsfU/1

Comment: could use js and do it clientside - would probably be easier than writing something to intercept the plugin code serverside

Comment: @Pete I'm definitely not sure that regex is the best solution. I've not yet worked with HTML parsers, so if somebody here is, please send me in the right direction :)

Comment: It's pretty simple, you just pass your text into the parser and if it's valid html, you can query it and the work with the result: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Using regex for matching HTML isn't good as you can see in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). However if your string is that you shown in OP you can use this regex pattern that select every string between `<li></li>` and add target string to it.

```
$newHtml = preg_replace("/(?<=<li>)(.*)(?=<\/li>)/", '<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>$1', $html);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/UMQNK)

---

**Update:** If you have multiple `ul` and want to match only `.foo` use this code

```
$newHtml = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=<ul\sclass=\"foo\">).*?(?=<\/ul>)/s", function($ma){
    return preg_replace("/(?<=<li>)(.*)(?=<\/li>)/", '<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>$1', $ma[0]);
}, $html);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/IOokf)

Comment: You haven't shown the bit that gets this only for a specific class

Comment: This one works only if the class only occurs in the last <ul> - look: https://3v4l.org/qaovZ

Comment: @Jasper You're right, one character missed. `.*` in pattern should be `.*?`. Check https://3v4l.org/IOokf